# Why do I get a 404 error installing Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm, version

I recently had my computer (OS- Mac OS X 10.6.8) wiped and I am re-installing all my development tools.
I have RVM installed once again; however, it won't let me install Ruby 1.9.3.

So far I have tried:

- `rvm install 1.9.3`
- `rvm install 1.9.3-p194`
- `rvm install 1.9.3-p448`
- `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

All returning the same command line error:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.

No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.

Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate

Certificates in '/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.

Requirements installation successful.

Installing Ruby from source to: /home/kjbradley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p448 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p448, this may take a while depending on your connection...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

The requested url does not exist(22): 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.bz2'
Trying ftp:// URL instead.

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
There was an error(7), please check /home/kjbradley/.rvm/log//*.log
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: `curl` is failing to download http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2 <- the link is dead

Comment: Do you have xcode installed, it might be worth an update to the Q to clearly state the OS version as well.

Comment: xcode is installed, updating question with OS now.

Comment: [It's known problem](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2095): http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/08/06/status-issue => Ruby’s tar packages distributed by ftp.ruby-lang.org are unreachable.

Comment: Bummer, bad timing for computer to crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Ruby-Lang.Org service is currently down. Status is at http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/08/06/status-issue/

EDIT: More timely updates and use of mirrors guidance at https://github.com/ruby/www.ruby-lang.org/issues/259

FINAL EDIT: The status page indicates the service is back up. I also just successfully ran `rvm install 1.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

This is mega lame.  I'm off to a bad start with Ruby...

There are mirrors.  Will this work?  Anyone know how to continue brew installation manually?

http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2