# RVM Ruby 2.0.0 installation fails in Ubuntu 11

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/11.10/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/unik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
The requested url does not exist(22): 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2'
Trying ftp:// URL instead.
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'ftp'
There was an error(6), please check /home/unik/.rvm/log//*.log
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.


$ cat /home/unik/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/1375803282_package_install_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_libgdbm-dev.log
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Suggested packages:
  sqlite3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgdbm-dev libsqlite3-dev libyaml-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 530 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,610 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libgdbm-dev i386 1.8.3-10 [25.1 kB]
Get:2 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libsqlite3-dev i386 3.7.7-2ubuntu2 [438 kB]
Get:3 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libyaml-dev i386 0.1.4-1 [66.4 kB]
Fetched 530 kB in 0s (1,089 kB/s)
Selecting previously deselected package libgdbm-dev.
(Reading database ... 709975 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libgdbm-dev (from .../libgdbm-dev_1.8.3-10_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libsqlite3-dev.
Unpacking libsqlite3-dev (from .../libsqlite3-dev_3.7.7-2ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libyaml-dev.
Unpacking libyaml-dev (from .../libyaml-dev_0.1.4-1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libgdbm-dev (1.8.3-10) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-dev (3.7.7-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libyaml-dev (0.1.4-1) ...


$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p448]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
[ruby-]2.0.0-head
ruby-head
```

Already tried to reinstall RVM with `rm -rf` all configs - didn't help, the problem persists.
What's the proper way to install ruby through RVM in Ubuntu?!
Also done `sudo chown -R unik:unik /home/unik/.rvm`, installed all necessary packages recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809294/installing-ruby-using-rvm-fails-without-trace). Any tries to explicitly throw `p247` gives nothing.

Comment: looks like `curl` is failing to download the [http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2](http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2)

Comment: I got that! :) But how else can I install another version of ruby?

Comment: rvm requirements
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Requirements installation successful.

Comment: [ruby-lang](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/08/06/status-issue/) is down

Comment: possible duplicate of [RVM - Installing ruby 1.9.3 URL Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085923/rvm-installing-ruby-1-9-3-url-error)

Comment: A transient 404 error isn't a programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

ok, thanks. Really ruby-lang.org is [down](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/08/06/status-issue/)